# What's the difference between "pervasive" and "ubiquitous"?

Tags: word-choice

The words [pervasive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pervasive) and [ubiquitous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ubiquitous) seem to mean almost the same thing.

> **pervasive**: existing in or spreading through every part of something <a *pervasive* odor>
>
> **ubiquitous**: existing or being everywhere at the same time : constantly encountered : widespread <a *ubiquitous* fashion>

Is there a difference in connotation or usage, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I think the difference is given in the definitions above; the difference between *pervasive* and *ubiquitous* is the difference between *somewhere* and *everywhere*. But if you add a qualifying prepositional clause, the difference goes away: *"pervasive among the younger generation"* and *ubiquitous in the younger generation"* mean the same thing.

Comment: As for connotation, I think of [pervasive](http://www.wordnik.com/words/pervasive#related) as being more negative than [ubiquitous](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ubiquitous). I think the links give examples that would back that up. When something is pervasive, it's like it is invading, saturating, taking over. When something is ubiquitous, it just is everywhere (as Peter Shor says). It, whatever "it" is, may have been pervasive before it became ubiquitous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Pervasive*** describes things that spread through a place to become established everywhere.

***Ubiquitous*** describes things that are everywhere in a place because it is the nature of that place to have those ubiquitous things.

The two words have slightly different origins -- *Pervasive* comes from *pervade* (to diffuse throughout) while *Ubiquitous* comes fro *ubiquity* (be everywhere).

Comment: Agreed it's often in *the nature of the place to have the ubiquitous things*, but it can also be *in the nature of ubiquitous things to be(come) everywhere*. At that point the senses overlap, but I'd still tend to see a *pervasive* presence as more of a "deliberate and directed invasion". Things can become ubiquitous just by drifting around everywhere.

Comment: There is a sense in which ubiquity is enduring pervasiveness. That is, we are conscious of the wide-spread presence of something rather than its (recent) arrival.

Comment: @Fortiter -- agreed -- right now kudzu is pervasive throughout the southeast U.S., eventually it will be ubiquitous.